# Why ansible module win_template didn't see my Windows folder?

Tags: ansible

I run ansible from an ubuntu server to configure a Windows server.
I have a problem with the `win_template` module. This is my `win_template` task:

```yaml
---
- name: copy hosts
  win_template:
    src: hosts
    dest: C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

- name: copy bootstrap.yaml
  win_template:
    src: bootstrap.yaml.j2
    dest: "C:\Service\bootstrap.yml2"
  notify: restart
```

When I run my role, I get the following error:

```
TASK [win : copy hosts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 09 August 2021  13:06:29 +0000 (0:00:00.061)       0:00:04.554 *********
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'
fatal: [win-01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\windows\\\\system32\\\\drivers\\\\etc\\\\hosts'"}
[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_failed) in callback plugin (<ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.callback.mail.CallbackModule object at 0x7fa1932605d0>): [Errno 99] Cannot
assign requested address

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
win-01                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But I don't understand why since I have a directory at this path:

```
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Why ansible didn't see it?

If I run other modules on the Windows server it works as expected. For example, the following task runs fine:

```yaml
- name: Start service
  win_service:
    name: my-service
    state: started
```

But I can't succeed copying the `hosts` file into `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Comment: Are you sure the user you are connecting with has sufficient privileges to access that file? From my (very old) memory, that file is only accessible to admin user on Windows.

Comment: "hosts" is a directory? It should be a text file with static entries about: IP address <-> hostnames

Comment: i`m also try different file, with same result.
Host it is file  like hosts file in /etc/hosts in ubuntu linux. And i can restart some service and run command so i Administrator permisions.